# Teamviewer doesn't show password

Tags: teamviewer

Why doesn't TeamViewer 12 show the password? I've removed it and installed a new one. But it didn't help.

See screenshot:

[image: TeamViewer Screen Shot]

Comment: That's not a screenshot, it's a photo. To take a screenshot on Windows, press the Print Screen button on your keyboard and paste it into an image editing program such as Paint by pressing CTRL+V.

Comment: I know how to take a screenshot on Windows. even though your comment is not an answer to my question. but thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Which version of Teamviewer you are using?

If you are using the version 12 or later, go to Extras -> Options -> Security and make sure "Random password..." option is not disabled.

If you are using another version, you may find it in Extras -> Options -> Advanced options -> Random password after each session, and make sure this option is not disabled.

NEW TV USER ->  I have the same problem, though I cannot enter "Extra/Options" as that requires a password and the TeamViewer account password does not work there.  ANY IDEAS?

Comment: "_Which version of Teamviewer you are using?_" TeamViewer 12 according to the question.